# Is systemctl edit systemd-journald a proper way to configure systemd-jounald.service?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

I started to learn Linux not long ago and have read some instructions about systemd and journald.

My question is: Is `systemctl edit systemd-journald` a proper way to configure systemd-journald.service?

According to the man page of journald.conf.d, we can put configuration files in these directories:

/etc/systemd/journald.conf

/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf

/run/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf

/usr/lib/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf

/usr/local/lib/systemd/*.conf.d/

I also noticed that `systemctl edit systemd-journald` would create `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d/override.conf` to override the defaults for systemd-journald.service which is not mentioned in the man page above.

Is it a proper way to configure systemd-journald.service?
What are the differences between all these directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `systemctl edit systemd-journald` a proper way to configure systemd-journald.service?

No. This command allows to change the service *definition*, not the service configuration.

The service definition contains information that systemd requires to run a service, and not the configuration of the service. The default service definition file is usually located in a lib directory, e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service`. The command `systemctl edit systemd-journald` allows to override values from this definition. It will create a file `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d/override.conf` that contains only values that differ from the service definition.

The preferred way to edit the journald configuration is to create a file with the suffix `.conf` in the directory `/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d`, e.g. `/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/50-local.conf`. This file may contain your configuration. For example, to make your journal persistent, the file should contain:

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
```

An alternative would be to edit the file `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. But this solution has one drawback: whenever a systemd update brings a new default configuration file, you're asked to merge your changes with the new default config.

Files within `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` are usually the place for files from your linux distribution and not for user configuration. Files within `/run` contain working data for running processes and not persistent configurations.

Further details may be found in the man page of [journald.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html).